# Creating 3D rotatable text using blender

Tags: opengl-es, blender

Hi i need to create a rotatable 3d  "c"(alphabet c)shaped object,i.e a logo kind of thing using blender 3d tool,i tried using text in blender but its not giving the feel of 3d object please help me out from this.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to hit tab to enter edit mode, select the faces to extrude(can hit "a" to select all), hit "e" key and move the mouse to extrude this text shape. Obviously render having added a light to the scene. (in case you are rendering it) And add a camera if you are not using the default one, and rotate it, or the object, so it renders other than a frontal view, to make it look more like a "3D object"

There's not yet an stack exchange site for 3d modeling questions (sadly, although [one is being voted](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-techniques-and-software) ) , so this question might fit better in Superuser. Anyway you need to explain the problem with more detail, or accuracy :)

Comment: please check this link                          http://www.atadcrazy.com/misc_files/ubuntu_logo_tutorial/ubuntu_logo_tutorial.html                                   actually i need to achieve this functionality,but as a beginner i cant understand completely by reading this.

Comment: @s.gfx:thanks a lot for the quick reply.same as the thing in the link i provided to u,i also need to create a logo like that.

Comment: Now working, I might give you some hints later on. Or faster, just upload the logo (if possible/convenient). Might take me less ;D

Comment: Which version of blender do you use? That tutorial is written for 2.4x. If you use blender 2.5x the UI will look differently. But you can still download 2.49 from [link](http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/)

Comment: @protal:am using blender 2.49b.more over am noob at blender and facing problem with bezier curves,while am trying to use those for creating a model with the help of background image.

Comment: So what are your problems with bezier? Can you add CV/nodes? Can you move them around? Can you change the handle type? Please be more specific.

Comment: @portal:sorry for the minimal info i had provided you in previous comment,actually i want to create a 3d model for alphabet "c",so i took a background image and trying to make it with bezier curves so i cant make the curves to fit exactly on to the image.even though i tried by changing the handle position and all.it's really screwing me down plz provide if there is any alternative for it.thanks in advance.

Comment: To move the CV of a bezier you have to switch into Editmode (TAB-Key) and select that CV with RMB (on the center ponit of that CV, not on one of the handle-endpoints). If you now press GKEY you can move that CV. If you press RKEY you can rotate that CV, i.e. rotate the handle. Just try this w/ a newly created bezier. If you select one of the handle endpoints you can change the "curvey" shape of that bezier. W/ Ctrl-LMB you add new CVs.

Comment: Another solution (if you are better w/ mesh tools) is a subsurf'd mesh: Just outline the shape of the "c" more or less w/ a mesh, fill it (AKEY, CTRL-F (? Sorry, currently have no blender at hand)), extrude (EKEY) and make that mesh subsurf'd.

Comment: @portal:Thanks a lot by providing me the hotkeys!!!finally i tried with CV of a bezier and got the shape of "c" but not exactly,problem is edges are not smooth!how to make them smooth so as both the logo in 2d image and mine looks alike....

Comment: Hmm, that's hard to tell without seeing the .blend-file or the image. Maybe you use vector-handles. Is the color of the handles in edit mode green? 
You can change the handle type of a selected CV by pressing HKEY (multiple times to cycle thru all possible modes; hopefully this is the right key, still no blender at hand ;))

Comment: nope its in normal pink color and i had tried making it clean and anyway its ok now.thz a lot for your help.

Comment: @portal,s.gfx:hi ppl i had created a 3d object and could render it on the iphone(device)  and now i want  to rotate the object using ui gestures or uitouches please let me know how to acheive this things.

Comment: That should be made via programming. Otherwise you are going to need to export to a format supporting animation and supported by the iphone. Which could be *.x or Collada, I don't know. For actually doing the animation, if I remember well, in frame zero hit i key and choose "location/rotation key", then move in the timeline till other frame, like 30, and hit i again, etc. Then export the scene as collada, or x.(or the needed format)